# Bipartite Matching with divisible tasks

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, bipartite, max-flow

I am trying to solve an extension of Assignment problem, where both tasks and the man hours are divisible.

for instance, a man X has 4 hours available in a day, can do 1/3 of task A in 2 hours, 1/4 of task B in 4 hours. Man Y has 10 hours available can do 1/5 of a task A in 1.3 hours, 1/8 of task B in 6 hours. Is there an extension of BiPartite matching which can solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can easily model this as a bipartite matching. However, it should be fairly easy to create a linear program for your problem. Just have for every worker a set of variables x_{i,j} which indicates how much of person i's time is allocated to task j.

Let h_i be the number of hours available for person i. Then, for every person i it must hold that

[image: constraint 1]

Let a_{i,j} be the "efficiency" of person i at task j, i.e., how much of the task the person can do in one hour. Then, for every task j it must hold that:

[image: constraint 2]

That's it. No integrality constraints or anything.

Comment: thanks Lucas. I am afraid I cannot use LP. Is there any other way I could solve this ?